# Silently print PDF on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, pdf, printing

i'm developing a Ruby on Rails application and i trying to print a PDF in silent mode, in the words, after user press print dialog confirmation, the application get the default printer and send it.

One of my options, is create a Google Chrome extension, that user can manage the printer and size of paper and etc, only once. And all time that user want to print a PDF the extension send it silently to the default printer.

So, how can i do this extension?
There's any way to manage user print config with js?

There are a better way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome extensions for silent print?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888183/chrome-extensions-for-silent-print)