# How to use chrome.printerProvider API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, printing

I find the developer link; https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/printerProvider

But, couldn't understand how to use it.

I've tried to print the current page without showing a print popup.

To be able to achieve it, I look printer provider, but was not successful.

*manifest.json*:

```json
{
  "name": "Print this page",
  "description": "Adds a print button to the browser.",
  "version": "1.1",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "printerProvider"
  ],


  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

*background.js*

```js
chrome.printerProvider.onGetCapabilityRequested.addListener(function callback) {
    alert(callback);
});


chrome.printerProvider.onGetPrintersRequested.addListener(function callback){
    console.log(callback);
});
```

But, these callbacks return nothing.

How can I use/trigger these events?

Comment: FYI: Asking for examples, etc. is considered a request for an off-site resource. Such requests are off-topic.  I have removed the portion of your question which was requesting such examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extensions for silent print?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888183/chrome-extensions-for-silent-print)

Answer (score 3):

the callback apis are called by Chrome when user clicks on pritn/ Ctl+P

- `onGetPrintersRequested()`  this should return the list of printers
- `onGetCapabilityRequested()` in the call back you need to pass the printer capabilities in the CDD format
- `onPrintRequested()` is invoked when user selects that printer and clicks print from the print dialogue

All these callback methods needs to be implemented in your `background.js`

And 
The call back functions you have provided are not correct. Refer to the documentations for the signature of the callbacks